# MPI partition and gather 2D array in Fortran

Tags: fortran, mpi

I have a 2D array where I'm running some computation on each process. Afterwards, I need to gather all the computed columns back to the root processes. I'm currently partitioning in a first come first serve manner. In pseudo code, the main loop looks like:

```
DO i = mpi_rank + 1, num_columns, mpi_size
   array(:,i) = do work here
```

After this is completed, I need to gather these columns into the correct indices back in the root process. What is the best way to do this? It looks like MPI_GATHERV could do what I want if the partitioning scheme was different. However, I'm not sure what the best way to partition that would be since `num_columns` and `mpi_size` are not necessarily evenly divisible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest the following approach:

1. Cut the 2D array into **chunks** of "almost equal" size, i.e. with local number of columns  close to `num_columns` / `mpi_size`.
2. Gather chunks with `mpi_gatherv`, which operates with **chunks** of different size.

To get "almost equal" number of columns, set local number of columns to integer value of `num_columns` / `mpi_size` and increment by one only for first `mod(num_columns,mpi_size)` mpi tasks.

The following table demonstrates the partitioning of (10,12) matrix on 5 MPI processes:

```
  01  02  03  11  12  13  21  22  31  32  41  42
  01  02  03  11  12  13  21  22  31  32  41  42
  01  02  03  11  12  13  21  22  31  32  41  42
  01  02  03  11  12  13  21  22  31  32  41  42
  01  02  03  11  12  13  21  22  31  32  41  42
  01  02  03  11  12  13  21  22  31  32  41  42
  01  02  03  11  12  13  21  22  31  32  41  42
  01  02  03  11  12  13  21  22  31  32  41  42
  01  02  03  11  12  13  21  22  31  32  41  42
  01  02  03  11  12  13  21  22  31  32  41  42
```

Here the first digit is an *id* of the process, the second digit is a number of local columns.
As you can see, processes 0 and 1 got 3 columns each, while all other processes got only 2 columns each.

Below you can find working example code that I wrote.
The trickiest part would be the generation of `rcounts` and `displs` arrays for MPI_Gatherv. The discussed table is an output of the code.

```
  program mpi2d
  implicit none
  include 'mpif.h'
  integer myid, nprocs, ierr
  integer,parameter:: m = 10       ! global number of rows
  integer,parameter:: n = 12       ! global number of columns
  integer nloc                     ! local  number of columns
  integer array(m,n)               ! global m-by-n, i.e. m rows and n columns
  integer,allocatable:: loc(:,:)   ! local piece of global 2d array
  integer,allocatable:: rcounts(:) ! array of nloc's (for mpi_gatrherv)
  integer,allocatable:: displs(:)  ! array of displacements (for mpi_gatherv)
  integer i,j


  ! Initialize
  call mpi_init(ierr)
  call mpi_comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, myid, ierr)
  call mpi_comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, nprocs, ierr)

  ! Partition, i.e. get local number of columns
  nloc = n / nprocs
  if (mod(n,nprocs)>myid) nloc = nloc + 1

  ! Compute partitioned array
  allocate(loc(m,nloc))
  do j=1,nloc
    loc(:,j) = myid*10 + j
  enddo

  ! Build arrays for mpi_gatherv:
  ! rcounts containes all nloc's
  ! displs  containes displacements of partitions in terms of columns
  allocate(rcounts(nprocs),displs(nprocs))
  displs(1) = 0
  do j=1,nprocs
    rcounts(j) = n / nprocs
    if(mod(n,nprocs).gt.(j-1)) rcounts(j)=rcounts(j)+1
    if((j-1).ne.0)displs(j) = displs(j-1) + rcounts(j-1)
  enddo

  ! Convert from number of columns to number of integers
  nloc    = m * nloc
  rcounts = m * rcounts
  displs  = m * displs

  ! Gather array on root
  call mpi_gatherv(loc,nloc,MPI_INT,array,
 &  rcounts,displs,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)

  ! Print array on root
  if(myid==0)then
    do i=1,m
      do j=1,n
        write(*,'(I04.2)',advance='no') array(i,j)
      enddo
      write(*,*)
    enddo
  endif

  ! Finish
  call mpi_finalize(ierr)

  end
```

Answer (score 0):

What about gathering in chunks of size `mpi_size`?

To shorten this here, I'll assume that `num_columns` is a multiple of `mpi_size`. In your case the gathering should look something like (`lda` is the first dimension of `array`):

```
DO i = 1, num_columns/mpi_size
  IF (rank == 0) THEN
    CALL MPI_GATHER(MPI_IN_PLACE, lda, [TYPE], array(1,(i-1)*mpi_size+1), lda, [TYPE], 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
  ELSE
    CALL MPI_GATHER(array(1, rank + (i-1)*mpi_size + 1), lda, [TYPE], array(1,(i-1)*mpi_size+1), lda, [TYPE], 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
  END IF
ENDDO
```

I'm not so sure with the indices and if this actually works, but I think, you should get the point.